# Invalid pointer error when using unique_ptr in tests

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I have a method that takes a `std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>` as input and processes it. In my unit test,

Here is how I create and initialize this argument: (on **stack**)

```
uint8_t testBytes[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> testBytesPtr = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(4);
testBytesPtr.reset(testBytes);
```

And it is passed to the method like:

```
myClass.processData(std::move(testBytesPtr));
```

At the end of my unit test, I get the following error message:

> free(): invalid pointer: 0xbed6b8c0

---

Here is how my unit test looks like:

```
#include "gtest.h"
#include "gmock.h" // for some deps

//...

TEST(MyClassUnittests, test1) {
    // Initializing the byte array.
    uint8_t testBytes[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> testBytesPtr = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(4);
    testBytesPtr.reset(testBytes);

    EXPECT_TRUE(myClass.processData(std::move(testBytestPtr));
}
```

I should also note that if the `testBytes` are initialized on the **heap** (e.g., `uint8_t* testBytes = new uint8_t()`), the error message becomes

> double free or corruption (fasttop): 0xb75c1e18

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: pointing a `unique_ptr` at an object in Automatic storage without providing a do-nothing deleter is a bad idea. Don't delete the stack.

Comment: If you didnt new it, dont delete it.

Comment: The provided snippet is all I have for my unit test. I am not deleting anything explicitly, so I am not sure how to avoid the _implicit_ delete.

Comment: @MatinKh the `unique_ptr` destructor `delete[]`'s the held pointer by default, unless you provide a different `deleter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete []`-ing something which isn't `new []`-ed, nor you own, is severely contra-indicated.

Look at these lines:

```
uint8_t testBytes[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> testBytesPtr = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(4);
testBytesPtr.reset(testBytes);
```

Removing the irrelevant ephemeral dynamic allocation leaves:

```
uint8_t testBytes[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> testBytesPtr(testBytes);
```

Which causes Undefined Behavior when the dtor kicks in.

Admittedly, you move the `std::unique_ptr` once, but that just shifts the exact point the blowup happens.

Considering the function you want to test, try this to get a properly allocated copy of the test-data:

```
uint8_t testBytes[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
auto testBytesPtr = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(std::size(testBytes));
std::copy(std::begin(testBytes), std::end(testBytes), &testBytesPtr[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining where the problem lies. However, I am still unclear on how to resolve the problem. I do not explicitly `delete[]` anything and the method only reads the data. Could you please clarify the solution?

Comment: Added how to get a properly allocated copy of the test-data.

Comment: @MatinKh: `unique_ptr` calls delete on its pointer when it is destroyed. That is `unique_ptr`'s entire purpose really. So if you did not create a pointer via `new` or `make_unique` then don't store it in a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: I do not think copying the data into the unique_ptr would solve the issue. I'm getting this error: `double free or corruption (fasttop): 0xb87b73a0`, regardless of whether I copy the data or not. This line alone `auto testBytesPtr = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(...);` gives me the error.

Comment: That line is innocuous, it just creates a unique_ptr owning a new piece of memory. But `.reset(somelocal)` is bad.